# @Annotation supported at Java 5 compliance level or above

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run one of my applications:

```
error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
```

The application uses AspectJ 6.0, AspectJWeaver 1.8, and SpringAspects 4.2 dependencies. I've checked that the JVM that is started is JDK 1.8 and JAVA_HOME is also set to my JDK 1.8 installation. Looking around from similar questions I see that the answer is to make sure that aspectjweaver be set to 1.8 and don't use AspectJ 1.5.4 with anything above JDK 1.6. Is there some other setting or configuration I can check?

A bit more of the stack trace:

```
Exiting with throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   
Error creating bean with name   org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor':  Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut   expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;  
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   
error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
```

Comment: what's IDE you're using?

Comment: Eclipse, but this is application is being run by command line. exec ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java  -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=1 ...

Comment: check your `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` again

Comment: Sure, doing a echo $JAVA_HOME and $JRE_HOME before the  exec command I get /myApp/bin/jdk1.8 for JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME is not set.  JRE_HOME not being set should be fine considering other boxes that run this app don't have it set either (just checked).

Comment: @Niru, can you please post your environment variable settings pointing to jdk1.8 and project facet settings?

Comment: what version of the spring-aspectweaver jar are you using?

Comment: I do not see a spring-aspectjweaver just Maven-org-aspectj_aspectjweaver 1.8  and Maven-org-aspectj_aspectjrt 1.8. Also I am not sure which facet settings you wish to see, but JAVA HOME is defined in script by JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME-$(ls -1vrd $APPROOT/jdk1.* | head -n1)}; export JAVA_HOME;

Comment: When you create a maven project in your eclipse it will take jdk 1.5 by default. Right click on project -> properties -> build path->  and remove 1.5 version add your installed jre location.  or Configure java version is `maven compiler plugin`

Comment: This is not being run through eclipse. Just command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: Don't deploy AspectJ 6.0 with conflicting AspectJWeaver 1.8 dependencies.

I suspect this won't be terribly helpful to anyone since the issue was incredibly niche. My local deployment had  AspectJ 6.0 jar which came with packaged with it a older version of AspectJWeaver jar. The run command for the application set classpath from /myApp/lib/*.

To find out all the dependencies I did: `sudo ps -ef | grep -i myApp` followed by `lsof -p <pid> > ~/tmp` . I was able to use this because while the application had failures the process still started. I noticed an older version of aspectJWeaver in the class path and ended up deleting AspectJ 6.0 jar from my local classpath folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the java home. Verify that it is less than 7.

Uses java -version.

In jboss, for instance, verifiy standalone.bat and standalone.config.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and stack trace with slightly different dependency versions.

Issue was lack of support for `Java 9`. Reverting to `Java 8` resolved the issue.